# Почему autodiscover_tasks в Celery не импортирует задачи, при подключенных сигналах?

Tags: django, celery

Есть проект, в нём, в одном из приложений есть сигналы и задачи, в файлах `tasks.py` и `signals.py`

Когда в `apps.py` я делаю так:

```
from django.apps import AppConfig


class MyAppConfig(AppConfig):
    name = 'proj.myapp'
    verbose_name = "MyApp"

    def ready(self):
        import proj.myapp.signals
```

то запуск `celery -A proj.taskapp worker -B -E -l info` выводит:

```
[tasks]
  . gglobal.taskapp.celery.debug_task
```

то есть мои задачи из `proj/myapp/tasks.py` не регистрируются.

Однако, если я в `def ready(self):`  пишу `pass`, то есть не импортирую сигналы как в примере выше, то все мои задачи из `proj/myapp/tasks.py` регистрируются нормально.

В чём может быть проблема ?

***ДОПОЛНЕНИЕ***

при этом, так:

```
def ready(self):
    import proj.myapp.tasks
    import proj.myapp.signals
```

работает, а вот так:

```
def ready(self):
    import proj.myapp.signals
    import proj.myapp.tasks
```

нет

Comment: Циклического импорта случайно нету?

Comment: Нет, ни на что не ругается. 
Просто при старте Celery не видно моих тасков.

Comment: На циклический импорт никто и не будет ругаться, проследите цепочку импортов по коду самостоятельно (хотя в данном случае не факт, что в этом дело, но циклических импортов таки лучше всегда избегать)

Comment: Вообще, в signals.py я как раз и импортировал задачу из tasks.py, но когда я удалял импорт и саму задачу из сигналов, то результат не менялся. 

В поисках причины такого поведения провёл несколько часов, но это ни к чему не привело.